# Python: Mutating List In Place v. Mutating List Copy

Tags: python, list

I am writing a calculator object that evaluates strings corresponding to ints/floats and operators in "()*/+". The functions excerpted below take a list of elements formed from the string containing only ints/floats and operators of the same rank (here * and /) and evaluates the expression, left to right, until there are no more operators.

```
def execute(s):
    while "*" in s or "/" in s:
        temp = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] == "*" or s[i] == "/":
                res = perform(s[i-1], s[i], s[i+1])
                del temp[-1]
                temp.append(res)
                for e in s[i+2:]:
                    temp.append(e)
                s = temp
                break
            else:
                temp.append(s[i])
    return s

def execute1(s):  
    while len(s) > 1:
        while "*" in s or "/" in s:
            for i in range(len(s)):
                if s[i] == "*" or s[i] == "/":
                    res = perform(s[i-1], s[i], s[i+1])
                    s[i-1:i+2] = [None, None, res]
            s = [e for e in s if e != None]
    return s
```

The first function does not mutate the list in place (which is a bad practice, I've learned) but is slower than the second function (because it must make a number of passes through the list equal to the number of operations) and uses more memory (because temp is created and modified during each pass).

Is there a way of doing it that does not mutate the list in place and performs the evaluation in only one pass?

Comment: Note, the next to the last line in execut1 does a full pass over s, and creates a temp...

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create a copy of `s` when it is passed in then use the same algorithm?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga. I tried that but ran into problems identifying the correct place in the copy of s to perform the substitutions, given that evaluations may not result in unique numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but ran into problems identifying the correct place in the copy of s to perform the substitutions

You can do it directly in `s` if you want to, you just need to keep track of where the current index (`i` below) is after mutating the list:

```
import sys

def perform(a, op, b):
    if op == '*':
        return a * b
    elif op == '/':
        return a / b
    raise ValueError('unknown op:', op)

def next_operator(lst, start, operators='*/'):
    nextop = sys.maxsize
    for op in operators:
        try:
            nextop = min(nextop, lst.index(op, start))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return nextop

def execute1(s):  
    i = 0
    while i := next_operator(s, i) != sys.maxsize:
        s[i-1:i+2] = [perform(*s[i-1:i+2])]
        i -= 1
    return s
```

output:

```
>>> execute1([5, '*', 3])
[15]
>>> execute1([2, "*", 3, "/", 4, "*", 5])
[7.5]
>>>
```

Comment: That's neat. I didn't know about the *argument for a function either - cheers. Your execute1 would perform all the multiplications first. How would you make it apply the multiplications and divisions left to right?

Comment: While we are replacing 3 list items with 1, the substitution is of i-1 to i+1, so i only needs to reduced by 1 at the end of the while loop. In fact, since we know that the list is {number}{operator}{number} repeated, i need not be modified at all because the next element after the substitution will be a number. The way you have it, however, i is set to -1 after the first substitution and the loop breaks after one pass and one evaluation only.

Comment: I've modified the answer to account for more operators, basically just iterate over them and return the first one.

Comment: `s[3:5] = [6]` shortens the list (`s`), and the algorithm finds all operators (it only breaks when there are no operators left).

Comment: Your modified function still sets `i` to -1 after the first substitution and exits the while loop. Try `execute1[2, "*", 3, "/", 4, "*", 5]`--it returns `[6, "/", 4, "*", 5]`. Even if `i` is left unchanged, the modified function performs all the multiplications and none of the divisions. For example `execute1([2, "*", 3, "/", 4, "*", 5])` returns `[6, "/", 20]` which does not evaluate to the conventional result of `2*3/4*5`, which is `7.5`.

Comment: The modified function does not perform according to the question specifications, as explained in my previous comment. In addition, the modified function is buggy because the first operator will always be found at index 1, so the modified function exits the loop after one pass, leaving the other operators unresolved. My edits to the modified function to correct these problems were rejected, so I withdrew the answer check.

Comment: @MikeyP Chill..? Sorry I couldn't get to this on your schedule, but some of us have to work. I didn't see your edit, but reviewers don't normally like edits to code that changes the semantic - which is probably why it was rejected.  As a question asker, you should do two things: all answers that helped you should be given an upvote, if an answer solved your question (or pointed you in the right direction so you could solve it yourself) then you should accept it.  If an answer helped you, but was buggy, and you have the solution.. then you should add your own answer (and accept it).

Comment: Ok my bad. I'm still new to this. Thanks for all your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem mutating list as long as you're not iterating over it with a for-loop, and even then you can modify the list as long as you don't change the size of it.

Comment: yes, but you're being very careful not to change the length _and_ you're not doing anything when you find that `s[i]` is None.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks. Keeping the size the same was why I added the None placeholders in the substitution.

Comment: It is considered not ideal to mutate the inputs to a function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's true, especially if you grew up when scheme were used to teach intro CompSci.  There is nothing intrinsically _wrong_ about it (but yes not considered ideal).\